# Runtime.getRuntime.exec() problem with running Word document

Tags: java, ms-word, runtime

when I write in commandline in windows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12>winword.exe /mOpenPage c:\Navod
ilo.doc
```

It starts the word document with the macro /mOpenPage.
I want to do the same thing from Java but its not going.

```
String[] cmd  = {"cmd","/c","c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\WINWORD.exe","/mOpenPage","c:\\Navodilo.doc"};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

and how to open the document without to specify the path to winword.exe? but also to use /mOpenPage Macro

help?

Comment: What do you need the "cmd.exe", "/c" and "start" for?

Comment: Hm... I dont hell know :) I found it from one example.

Comment: Thanks, without start and without ".exe" its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String cmd = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\WINWORD.exe /mOpenPage c:\\Navodilo.doc";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: and how to opent the document without to specify the path to winword.exe? but also to use /mOpenPage Macro

Comment: Sorry, but that is too much of a change to your original question ;-) I'm not on Windows so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `Desktop.open(File file)` which will open the default application for your Word document. This is a better approach as you don't have to worry about where Office is installed.

Comment: And how would he pass the `/mOpenPage` flag?

Answer (score -1):

Runtime.getRuntime.exec() does not open up a cmd window you have to invoke it with `"cmd"` as its argument and then use the inputstream to send you `winword.exe`command

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=138974&tstart=140442

Comment: Edited, I tried with just "cmd" but again it doesnt open the document

Comment: take a look at the link I added, something like what tushar_zaware says